# Open ClickOnce application deployed in shared folder by a web browser

Tags: clickonce

I publish [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) application on a shared folder with UNC //Server/Folder.
I use visual studio 2010 and publish this application by the ClickOnce publish wizard.

After publish, I want to run it on my web browser (for example, FireFox and Internet Explorer). I use the address `//Server/Folder`. Now, I click on the setup file. It will be downloaded to my computer to `C:/Users/duytn/Downloads/`. Then, I click on this setup to run. An error occur. This is its detail:

```
SOURCES

Deployment URL: file:///C:/Users/duytn/Downloads/WMEditor.application

ERROR SUMMARY

Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of C:\Users\duytn\Downloads\WMEditor.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Downloading file:///C:/Users/duytn/Downloads/WMEditor.application did not succeed.
    + Could not find file 'C:\Users\duytn\Downloads\WMEditor.application'.
    + Could not find file 'C:\Users\duytn\Downloads\WMEditor.application'.
    + Could not find file 'C:\Users\duytn\Downloads\WMEditor.application'.
```

I think this setup can not find its manifest (*.Application file). I want to publish the project on a shared folder. And run it by web browser.

Comment: aren't you supposed to click at the .application file?

Answer (score 0):

You should run the setup from the shared folder, as the `setup.exe` looks for the deployment file on the same folder the setup.exe resides in.

Use `file://server/sharefolder/setup.exe` as the link in your web browser and click "run".

Comment: I'm sorry. I published project on share folder. I want to run it on browser. But I type address as: file://server/sharefolder/setup.exe . Run -> This setup file will be auto downloaded into my computer. Now, if I run on this setup. Error occur. So, how I can run this setup by browser. (Example: I follow address file://server/folder/setup.exe to download this file. After that, I run this setup on my local computer. I think it will download manifest from shared folder but NO. It download app.Application file in where browser put setup after download. ex: c:/download/. So setup can not run )

Comment: @thanhduyspkt: which browser are you using? i noticed clickonce is supported only in IE (correct me if i'm wrong).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand "now I want to run it from my web server". Do you mean you want to move it from the file share to the webserver?

The installation URL of a ClickOnce deployment is part of the identity of the deployment. You can't just change it without handling the change (more on that in a minute). And you can't just move hte deployment and expect it to work. ClickOnce is going to look at that installation URL for the files, no matter where you put them.

If you want to move your deployment from the file share to a webserver, you can do that, but you need to leave the old one in place in order to re-point to the new one, and you need to set the installation and Update URLs correctly.

Note that in Visual Studio, you can use any publishing file location you want to, but the installation URL must be the same as the location from where the users are installing it. So you can publish it to a local folder or to a file share and copy it to the webserver, but you have to get the folder structure the same, and the installation URL has to point to the webserver.